# How to have <picture> elements with different links on each image?

Tags: javascript, html

Time ago I had a header implemented with a Bootstrap carousel: You know, something like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="pic1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><a href="example.com"><img src="pic2.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Pay attention to that link on "pic2.jpg", this will be fun...

Recently, I have been asked to use `<picture>` elements, so now it is posible to display images for mobile devices:

```
<div class="item">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic1-small.jpg">
        <img src="pic1.jpg">
     </picture>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic2-small.jpg">
        <img src="pic2.jpg">
     </picture>
</div>
```

And here is the tricky question: I need to add a link only in the mobile image (pic2-small.jpg).

(Well, in fact could be links on every image, or none at all, only in the mobile image, only in the desktop image... This is managed by the administrator user)

So, I can't do this because the link should be only for pic2-small, not pic2:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="example.com">
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic2-small.jpg">
            <img src="pic2.jpg">
         </picture>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I did is this:

```
<div class="item" onclick="header_onclick(this)">
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="pic2-small.jpg?target=pic2-small-link">
        <img src="pic2.jpg">
     </picture>
     <a id="pic2-small-link" href="example.com" style="display: none"></a>
</div>

<script>
function header_onclick(carousel_item)
{
    var current_src = carousel_item.querySelector("img").currentSrc;                
    if (typeof current_src === "undefined") {
        return;
    }

    var src_parts = current_src.split("?target=");                
    if (src_parts.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
            
    var link = document.getElementById(src_parts[1]);                
    if (link) {
        link.click();
    }
}
</script>
```

- An `onclick` event in the carousel item and a javascript function.
- A `target` value in the URL of the image.
- A hidden `<a>` with the destination URL.

The magic is in this line:

```
var current_src = carousel_item.querySelector("img").currentSrc;
```

`currentSrc` has the URL of the image that the browser is currently showing according to the screen size. So, from that URL I take the `target` parameter and use it to get the corresponding link and then execute it.

All this is working, but I feel it too hacky for my taste. I'm not very experienced with the `<picture>` element, so my question is: this could be resolved in a better way?

Comment: This question belongs here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it, I already asked the question there. Thanks!